# PHP Regex to extract phone number from + to first non-number

Tags: php, regex

EDIT: I'm doing this because the data I've been provided has hundreds of newline-separated entries in this format, and I need to incorporate microformats into the address data. Thus if the string provided is as below, I need to output:

```
<p><span itemprop="telephone">+1 800 123 456</span> (toll free) from overseas</p>
```

--

I need a regex to extract a phone number from the format below:

> +1 800 123 456 (toll free) from overseas

The data I have been provided has consistently been entered in this format, so effectively, a regex to get everything from and including a "+" up to the first non-numerical character.

Comment: Well can you provide your attempts?

Comment: Instead of explicitly pulling out the phone number. could you just remove everything that isnt a number or a plus sign using `preg_replace('/[^0-9\+]/', '', $phone_number);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a regex you can use something like this:

```
\+[\d\s]+

$re = '/(\+[\d\s]+)/'; 
$str = "+1 800 123 456 (toll free) from overseas\n"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

On the other hand, you can use what [castis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/465895/castis) suggested, to use a preg_replace to replace the characters you don't want by empty string and keep the rest, like:

```
preg_replace('/[\D\+]/', '', $phone_number);
```